# kibana error in displaying some data

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana, cidr

Im indexing from MongoDB 2.4.9 to Elasticsearch 1.1.1 using the River Plugin. And of course, I'm using Kibana3

The documents in the MongoDB that I have contain a cidr. The cidr is in the format:

```
"cidr" : "0.0.0.0/00"
```

I have a table and a term panels in my kibana dashboard.

The Table panel shows the part `0.0.0.0/`

and the term panel shows the part `00`

I need both panels to show the WHOLE cidr value! Like this: `0.0.0.0/00`

Does anyone have any idea why these two panels are behaving this way?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elasticsearch is processing the input, and splitting on the "/".  logstash should be creating a "raw" version of the field.  Try referencing "cidr.raw" in kibana.

If you're not using logstash, you'll need to update the elasticsearch mapping to either set the field to not_analyzed or to add the ".raw" field yourself.

The reference for using not_analyzed [is here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#custom-field-mappings).  Grab the current mapping, edit it, and post it back.

To add ".raw", check out the [logstash default template](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/v1.3.1/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json), which shows you the magic to make a multi_field with ".raw".

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I'm not using Logstash for indexing my data, I'm using the river plugin to index from mongodb and so, I think a raw version is not created?

Comment: In that case, update the mapping to set the field to "not_analyzed" or create a multi-field ".raw" version.  I'll try to find some examples and update the answer.